Moving EDB to a New Exchange Server
I'm trying to transfer information from the "old" EDB to the new Exchange Server 2019.
Before starting, I checked the database: esentutl.exe /mh ".\Mailbox Database 0469201319.edb"
Result: State: Dirty Shutdown
Tried to restore via: eseutil.exe /R "E00"
Result:

Operation terminated with error -1216 (JET_errAttachedDatabaseMismatch, An outstanding database attachment has been detected at the start or end of recovery, but database is missing or does not match attachment info) after 2.250 seconds.,

Next command: eseutil.exe /R "E00" /l C:\OldMailboxDatabase\ /d C:\OldMailboxDatabase\
Result: Operation completed successfully in 14.219 seconds.
I check again: esentutl.exe /mh ".\Mailbox Database 0469201319.edb"
Result: State: Clean Shutdown

Next I try to create a recovery base: I write:
New-MailboxDatabase -Recovery -Name DBR -Server SRV-MAIL -EdbFilePath "C:\OldMailboxDatabase\Mailbox Database 0469201319.edb" -LogFolderPath C:\OldMailboxDatabase\

for a while the terminal goes into thought, but does not freeze, I wait, I get an error:
Failed to connect to target server "SRV-MAIL". Error: A WMI exception
occurred on server 'SRV-MAIL.tk.local': Call cancelled + CategoryInfo: 
InvalidOperation: (:) [New-MailboxDatabase],
InvalidOperationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
[Server=SRV-MAIL,RequestId=0f5346e0-55b7-4065-8242-bbbf29af2531,TimeStamp=09/16/2024
9:56:51] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-InvalidOperationException]
31BAC08B,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemConfigurationTasks.NewMailboxDatabase
+ PSComputerName : srv-mail.tk.local


I tried to solve the problem with the following steps:

restarted WMI services: net stop winmgmt /y net start winmgmt.
made sure that Windows Management Instrumentation service is running.
cleaning and restoring WMI repository I do: winmgmt /verifyrepository I get: WMI database is consistent I do: winmgmt /salvagerepository I get: WMI database is consistent
In the registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WBEM\CIMOM created a new string parameter (REG_SZ) with the name Operation_Timeout. set the value: 240. edited the TimeOutMs parameter and set the value to 200000, it was 2000. restarted WMI services.
Checked user access

Add-RoleGroupMember -Identity "Organization Management" -Member "User123"
All rights are there.
Could you tell me please, what else could it be? how to fix this problem? what options to try?
Thank you very much!
